# Is “Golden Freddy” a separate character?

Tags: character, five-nights-at-freddys

In *Five Nights at Freddy’s* (2023), the animatronic mascots at the abandoned pizzeria are:

- Freddy Fazbear (a brown bear),
- Bonnie (a blue rabbit),
- Chica & Mr Cupcake (a yellow chicken with a pink cupcake), and
- Foxy (a red fox).

[image: Foxy, Bonnie, Freddy, and Chica (& Mr Cupcake) on stage at Freddy Fazbear’s Pizza Place]

On the fifth night, a bear that resembles Freddy (but with some signs of damage, e.g. a missing eye (and a sightly lighter complexion(?))) turns up at Abby Schmidt (Piper Rubio)’s home.  This “Golden Freddy” promptly disposes of Aunt Jane (Mary Stuart Masterson) before [Abby asks](https://youtu.be/8HaUZsixz9g?si=bg8nOOw-3H0Jw5A_):

> “Freddy?”

The blond Ghost Kid (Grant Freely) replies:

> “Not Freddy.”

Abby and Golden Freddy then take a taxi to the restaurant, but Golden Freddy mysteriously disappears before Abby enters the building.

[image: “Golden Freddy” with Abby in the taxi on the way to Freddy Fazbear’s Pizza Place]

**Is this “Golden Freddy” character different from the regular Freddy Fazbear?**

How are they different? (other than the damage)

Why does the blond Ghost Kid say “Not Freddy.”? (surely it is at least *some kind* of Freddy)

Abby knows all the other animatronics, why doesn’t she recognise this character?

Why don’t we ever see Golden Freddy inside the pizzeria or with the other animatronics?

Comment: My knowledge of FNAF is enough to be able to confirm that Golden Freddy is a separate animatronic from regular Freddy, but not enough to elaborate on how.

Comment: https://fivenightsatfreddys.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_Freddy

Comment: @BCdotWEB Information on that page is about the Golden Freddy in the games/books, it doesn’t really have anything to do with the Golden Freddy in the movie.  On the same site, there is a page for the [Golden Freddy in the film](https://freddy-fazbears-pizza.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_Freddy_(Film)) but it doesn’t answer my questions.